# Pushing an array from a for loop and storing the objects into mongoose, is repeating the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am posting an array, which contains the name elements like this, '[Training 1, Training 2, Training 3]', these array elements has their own '_ids'. i need to save these element's object `_id` into another model, which has a ref.

```
var TrainingNameSchema = new Schema({
    trainingname: {
        type: String
    }
    });

var TrainingLevelSchema = new Schema({
    levelname: {
         type: String
     },
     trainingnames: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'TrainingName'
    }]
});
```

i am using a for loop to save it when posted, code as below,

```
    var newLevel = {
        levelname: req.body.groupname
    };

    var levarr = req.body.levtrainingnames;

    new TrainingLevel(newLevel)
    .save()
    .then(function(lev){
        for(var i = 0; i<levarr.length; i++){
            TrainingName.findOne({
                trainingname: levarr[i]
            })
            .then(function(name){

                lev.trainingnames.push(name._id);
                console.log(lev);

                lev.save()
                .then(function(doc){
                    console.log(doc);
                    res.redirect('/settings/trainings');
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

when i `console.log(doc)`, its output is correct,

```
{ trainingnames: 
   [ 5a64e2dde4dde5080d38c48a,
     5a64e49870b92c0834914605,
     5a6501807432a00d6873c5f6 ],
  _id: 5a66bab1869d0e032e643762,
  levelname: 'Level A',
  __v: 1 }
```

But when i check the db, its repeating itself, please help, thanks in advance,

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a66bab1869d0e032e643762"),
"trainingnames" : [
    ObjectId("5a64e2dde4dde5080d38c48a"),
    ObjectId("5a64e2dde4dde5080d38c48a"),
    ObjectId("5a64e49870b92c0834914605"),
    ObjectId("5a6501807432a00d6873c5f6"),
    ObjectId("5a64e2dde4dde5080d38c48a"),
    ObjectId("5a64e49870b92c0834914605"),
    ObjectId("5a6501807432a00d6873c5f6")
],
"levelname" : "Level A",
"__v" : 3
```

Comment: You need to remove `lev.save()`, `push` does an insert

Comment: but, how do i save the `_ids` that are generated..?? please help

Comment: can you post the result after commenting the save and expected result?

Comment: db, showed an empty array, when posted, since the ids are not saved after push.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, we need to `update` not `save` for every iteration

```
new TrainingLevel(newLevel)
    .save()
    .then(function(lev){
        for(var i = 0; i<levarr.length; i++){
            TrainingName.findOne({
                trainingname: levarr[i]
            }).then(function(name){            
              lev.update({$push : {trainingnames : name._id}}, function(err, doc){
                if(err) console.log(err);
                console.log(doc);
              })
            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate, worked like a charm, was struggling from yesterday, me a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

A better and simpler approach would be to do a bulk insert using **[`insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#insertmany_insertMany)** of the training names first in one step then use the id's returned from
the write operations to use as the training level model:

```
const names = req.body.levtrainingnames.map(t => ({ trainingname: t }));
TrainingName.insertMany(names).then(docs => (
    new TrainingLevel({
        levelname: req.body.groupname,
        trainingnames: docs.map(doc => doc._id)
    }).save()   
)).then(doc => {
    console.log(doc);
    res.redirect('/settings/trainings');
})
```